# Analytic continuation of $\sum (z/a)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, analytic-continuation

I'm having trouble continuing this function beyond its convergence radius, $R=a$.

$$f(z)=\sum (z/a)^n$$

Given the context (a textbook in complex analysis) I suspect it should have a simple closed-form expression. I've tried differentiating and trying to relate it to the geomtric series, but so far I haven't had any success.

Any hint or idea on how to analytic continuate it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: it is a geometric series.  No need to "relate it" to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $|z/a|<1$ the sum is $\frac{1}{1-(z/a)} = \frac{a}{a-z}$. That is the continuation.

Answer (score 1):

The geometric series $f_{z_0}$ has a series expansion with center $z_0=0$ and radius of convergence $R=|a|$ with $a$ a being a *[simple pole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_(complex_analysis))*.
\begin{align*}
f_{z_0}(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z}{a}\right)^n=\frac{a}{a-z}
\end{align*}

When we consider a series expansion around another point $z_1$ we know that the radius of convergence is the distance from $z_1$ to the nearest singularity which is $a$ in this case.

> In order to obtain an *[analytic continuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation)* of $f_{z_0}(z)=\frac{a}{a-z}$ we can select a point $z_1$ *within* the disc $D_{z_0}$ of convergence of the series expansion of $f_{z_0}$ around $z_0=0$. This way we obtain a function $f_{z_1}$
>
> \begin{align*}
> f_{z_1}(z)&=\frac{a}{a-z}\\
> &=\frac{a}{(a-z_1)-(z-z_1)}\\
> &=\frac{a}{a-z_1}\cdot\frac{1}{1-\frac{z-z_1}{a-z_1}}\\
> &=\frac{a}{a-z_1}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{z-z_1}{a-z_1}\right)^n
> \end{align*}
>
> This function converges within the disc $D_{z_1}$ with center $z_1$ and radius $|z_1-a|$.

Depending on the choice of $z_1$ the disc $D_{z_1}$ may contain points which are *not* inside $D_{z_0}$. This can be the starting point for creating a *[germ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation#Formal_definition_of_a_germ)* of $f_{z_0}$.